# pandas How to insert the column name of datafram into the mysql table as value instead of inserting it as field name

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe

i have a datafram simplely like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
dataA = [["2005-1-20", "9:35", 5, 15, 5], ["2005-1-20", "9:40", 8, 6, 1], ["2005-1-20", "9:45", 7, 5, 6],
    ["2005-1-20","9:50", 4, 8, 3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data = dataA, columns=["date", "min", "vala", "valb", "valc"])

df
 
        date    min   vala  valb  valc
0   2005-1-20   9:35    5   15    5
1   2005-1-20   9:40    8   6     1
2   2005-1-20   9:45    7   5     6
3   2005-1-20   9:50    4   8     3
```

there is a problem, this datafram (df) changes it's columns name Every 5 minutes，

and i want to get columns name : date min   vala    valb  valc ,insert into a mysql table as value ,
so how do i insert the column name to mysql table as value, not as a field name

i try below ,but it insert as  field name

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:password@www.google.com:3306/dbcon')
df.to_sql('tableA', engine,if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([df.columns, df]))
```

before you do `df.to_sql(...)`

taken from here [conversion column names into first row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43975986/conversion-column-names-into-first-row)