# How to remove data frame header and make it a row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using tabula to read tables form pdf files.

```
tables = tabula.read_pdf(file, pages="all")
```

This works fine. Now tables is a list of dataframes, where each data frame is a table fromt eh pdf file.

However the table rows are indexed 0,1,2,3.. etc. But the first row is taken as the column name or header of each dataframe.

Current dataframe:

```
  Component manufacturer               DMNS
0         Component name               KL32/OOH8
1         Component type               LTE-M/NB-IoT
2       Package markings               <pin 1 marker>\ ksdc 99cdjh
3              Date code               Not discerned
4           Package type               127-pin land grid array (LGA)
5           Package size               26.00 mm × 10.11 mm × 3.05 mm
```

Desired Dataframe:

```
        0                                1
0       Component manufacturer           DMNS
1       Component name                   KL32/OOH8
2       Component type                   LTE-M/NB-IoT
3       Package markings                 <pin 1 marker>\ ksdc e99cdjh
4       Date code                        Not discerned
5       Package type                     127-pin land grid array (LGA)
6       Package size                     26.00 mm × 10.11 mm × 3.05 mm
```

How can I do this transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [tabula docs on `read_pdf`](https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tabula.html#tabula.io.read_pdf) state, you can add `pandas_options` and they even give the one you need as an example - `{'header': None}`. So (something like) this should do the trick:

```py
tabula.read_pdf(file, pages="all", pandas_options={'header': None})
```

Edit: So apparently that should only work if you set `multiple_tables` to `False` which is not the default. I'd play with the options a bit and if it doesn't give the desired result, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43975986/conversion-column-names-into-first-row) is a post on how to turn the column names into the first row.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do what your question asks:

```py
df = df.T.reset_index().T.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
                        0                              1
0  Component manufacturer                           DMNS
1          Component name                      KL32/OOH8
2          Component type                   LTE-M/NB-IoT
3        Package markings    <pin 1 marker>\ ksdc 99cdjh
4               Date code                  Not discerned
5            Package type  127-pin land grid array (LGA)
6            Package size  26.00 mm × 10.11 mm × 3.05 mm
```

Explanation:

- Transpose the dataframe so we can use `reset_index()` to convert the index (i.e., the original column labels) to a new initial column
- Transpose it again so the new initial column becomes an initial row, and use `reset_index()` to get a fresh integer index.